# Python 3 While Loop within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, while-loop

> Write a function named `powPosInt`. This function will take two integer input parameters, named `x` and `p`. This function will compute the value of `x` to the power of `p`, where `p >= 0`, which is defined as `x` to the power of `p = x × · · · × x`
> | {z }
> p times
> or 1 if p is 0.
>
> The function will return this computed result. This function should not produce any console output.
>
> For computing `x` to the power of `p`
> , I am requiring that you implement the calculations using a while loop and an accumulator variable.
>
> Examples of values you should test with: `x = 2`, `p = 3` should return `8`. `x = 1`, `p = 4`
> should return `1`. `x = 7`, `p = 0` should return `1`. `x = −3`, `p = 2` should return `9`.
> `x = −3`, `p = 3` should return `−27`.

This is what I have so far, I am having trouble figuring out how to put a while loop within this function. I am asking on here for help as my TEACHER will not assist, (he wants us to treat his class like the real world where we will have to figure out solutions on our own... why pay his salary right?)

```py
def powPosInt(x,p):
    number = p
    count = 0
    while (number != 0):
        answer = (x**p)
        count = count + 1
        if (p<0):
            answer = (x**(1/abs(p)))
    return answer
```

Comment: You never assign the variable `number`.

Comment: Doesn't the teacher teach the basic principles before giving an assignment?

Comment: that's the problem he doesn't teach it. and it is to late to drop from his course..

Comment: but number is = p would be the assignment.

Comment: "This is what I have so far, I am having trouble figuring out how to put a while loop within this function." `**` gives you the result for the calculation directly, which makes the loop useless. Can you think of something you can *do repeatedly* that calculates the desired result? Hint: think about how the definition was written in the problem statement.

Comment: def powPosInt(x,p):
    number = p
    count = 0
    while (number != 0):
        answer = (x**p)
        count = count + 1
        if (p<0):
            answer = (x**(1/abs(p)))
    return answer

Comment: "using a while loop and an accumulator variable." Do you understand what the teacher means by "accumulator variable?" If not, *did you try putting that into a search engine*?

Comment: Edit your question if you have code clarifications.  Don't paste code in a comment as it is unreadable.

Comment: yes just edited the question/ example, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Using accumulation means you need to create a variable that will store the result, and while loop will multiply it by `x` each step. You shouldn't use the `**` operator.

```
steps = 0
result = 1
while (steps < p):
    result *= x
    steps += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def powPosInt(x,p):
    number = p
    count = 0
    while (number != 0):
        answer = (x**p)
        count = count + 1
        if (p<0):
            answer = (x**(1/abs(p)))
    return answer
```

I see a number of problems here:

- A loop for calculating powers will be using repeated multiplication, *not* exponentiation. The intent here is to assume Python doesn't *have* an exponentiation operator, otherwise this assignment would be futile.
- There's *no* reason to handle negative powers, the specifications clarly call for `p >= 0`. Hence your final `if` block is unnecessary.
- This is a style issue only: you should get into the habit of using meaningful variable names. The *only* situation in which I use single-letter variables nowadays is a short-lived, non-nested, loop where the variable name is irrelevant (and I use `i` for that). For any other situation, I use explanatory names (yes, not even `j` or `k` for nested loops). And I'm even starting to move away from using `i` for these simple cases.

Having said all that, I'd suggest revisiting your solution to take those into account.

---

Once you've done so, you can refer to the code below for one solution:

```py
def powPosInt(myBase, myPower):
    result = 1
    for _ in range(myPower):
        result *= myBase
    return result
```

And, if you wanted to go for extra credits<sup>(a)</sup>, you could put in place contractual checks to ensure callers are doing the right thing:

```py
def powPosInt(myBase, myPower):
    if type(myBase) != int:  raise TypeError("Base must be an integer")
    if type(myPower) != int: raise TypeError("Power must be an integer")
    if myPower < 1:          raise ValueError("Power must be >= 1")

    result = 1
    for _ in range(myPower):
        result *= myBase
    return result
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Or risk losing marks for being a smart-alec. This depends very much on the personality of your teacher :-)

Comment: correction all this is the correct program as I copied the wrong one..